# What's the difference with installing Bootstrap via the CDN or using the bootstrap rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Just adding the CDN link seems so much easier, I have a good feeling that I'm missing the benefits that the bootstrap rails (sass) gems provides

Comment: With gem you can update boostrap easy ! And using sass is important when you try to change the design of bootstrap. I recommand gem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDN only serves CSS. With the gem you get SASS source of Bootstrap, and you can tweak the variables and do other customizations from your sass files.